# list of lists to a dict, where first list is the key of the dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary

the list is like this

```
['language', 'edition']
['Pascal', 'third']
['Python', 'fourth']
['SQL', 'second']
```

and i would like the dict to have 'language' and 'edition' as keys where the other lists would be values, see desired output

```
{"language": "Pascal","edition": "third"},{"language":"Python","edition":"fourth"},{"language": "SQL","edition":"second"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of `dict` and `zip`

```
items = [['language', 'edition'], ['Pascal', 'third'], ['Python', 'fourth'], ['SQL', 'second']]

keys = items[0]
options = items[1:]

my_dict = [dict(zip(keys, k)) for k in options]
print(my_dict)

>>> [{'language': 'Pascal', 'edition': 'third'}, {'language': 'Python', 'edition': 'fourth'}, {'language': 'SQL', 'edition': 'second'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

in one line:

```
{n:{'language':a,'edition':b} for n,(a,b) in enumerate(given_list)}
```

Comment: While you are in the right direction, running this by itself will 1) throw an `unhashable type: 'dict'` error, 2) assume the keys are always `language` and `edition`, and 3) not exclude the first item in the list (which are the specified keys)

Comment: @Wondercricket you are right, I overlooked that the output by OP is incorrect. I  have edited my answer :)